# SSAS Restore - Full server path location Issue / Server/Folder Permissions

Tags: server, permissions, ssas, restore, cube

Any help would be appreciated. I am failing to restore an SSAS cube when the full server path to the folder is provided in the code.

The SSAS cube restore works when I give the normal drive path to the code (eg. F:\OLAP) but when I assign the server-name to the same shared folder (\servername\F\OLAP) then the following error is generated:

```
[Analysis Services Execute DDL Task] Error: File system error: The following error occurred during a file operation:  Cannot create a file when that file already exists. . (\\servername\F\OLAP\28AEC4E6A0A74DF88A3F\CUBE.5.db).
```

The code is similar to the one below and has the AllowOverwrite property yo 'true'

```
<Restore xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
  <File>\\10.10.10.10\e\Live\DWH\OLAP_backup.abf</File>
  <DatabaseName>OLAP</DatabaseName>
  <AllowOverwrite>true</AllowOverwrite>
  <DbStorageLocation xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2008/engine/100/100">F:\OLAP\</DbStorageLocation>
</Restore>
```

I am not sure how if any of you have already come across this and know of the root cause or easy fix?

Thank you

Comment: I am running the code from SSIS and running it manually from Data Tools

Comment: Fixed - I have created a new folder to backup and restore the cube and it is working fine. Not sure why it was not Restoring to the old folder.